# Many2Many Relationships in Entiry Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp

So, after following the kind advice of @zadqvb8 in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?hubRefSrc=email&utm_source=lfemail&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=lfnotification#lf-content=177107930:682390858, I still cannot make this work.

Does anybody have Real Live Experience in establishing and using **Many2Many Relationships** between one entity on one side (A) and several different entities on the other side (BCD...) in **Entity Framework Core**? (Let's call the resulting table "AB").

The framework does not support that out-of-the-box, and the workaround does not yield any actual records created in the relation...

Background: Tags are the entities on one side, and several asset classes are the other side... I am just trying to add tags to an asset. The described solution does not generate entries in the (AB) relationship table.

Using SQLite, coz this is an UWP app... Pls don't hate.

**--Update 2017-04-29 13:39 CET**

Very much appreciate the offer to help.

To keep it simple, I will post the code to create a m2m between ModelImage and ModelTag:

```
public class ModelImage
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ModelImageId { get; set; }

    public List<ModelImageTag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class ModelTag
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ModelTagId { get; set; }

    public List<ModelImageTag> Images { get; set; }
}

public class ModelImageTag
{
   public int ModelImageId { get; set; }
   public ModelImage ModelImage { get; set; }

   public int ModelTagId { get; set; }
   public ModelTag ModelTag { get; set; }
}
```

There is more to those classes, but I guess these properties suffice

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ModelImageTag>().HasKey(x => new { x.ModelImageId, x.ModelTagId });
    modelBuilder.Entity<ModelImageTag>().HasOne(x => x.ModelImage).WithMany(x => x.Tags).HasForeignKey(x => x.ModelTagId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ModelImageTag>().HasOne(x => x.ModelTag).WithMany(x => x.Images).HasForeignKey(x => x.ModelImageId);
}
```

And this is the section adding a relationship:

```
ModelImage image = ....;
ModelTag tag = ...;

ModelImageTag iTag = new ModelImageTag { ModelImage = image, ModelTag = tag};
tag.Images.Add(iTag);
image.Tags.Add(iTag);

Context.SaveChanges();
```

I tried this setting the IDs in ModelImageTag, or the entity reference, no result.

What am I missing? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your entities and the `OnModelCreating()`?

Comment: [this](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration) page has a simple example

Comment: We can't help you fix code we don't see.

Comment: Made an edit, pls review.

Comment: I prefer the syntax `modelBuilder.Entity<ModelImage>().HasMany(c => c.Tags).WithMany(i => i.Images).Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ModelImageId).MapRightKey("ModelTagId").ToTable("ModelImageTag"));`  See [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/). Don't think you need the lines Images.Add and Tags.Add either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are giving the wrong **ForeignKey**  for the `ModelImageTag` entity created table. Many to many relationship currently is not supported in EFCore as you known. So we use a join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.

For this code line `modelBuilder.Entity<ModelImageTag>().HasOne(x => x.ModelImage).WithMany(x => x.Tags).HasForeignKey(x => x.ModelTagId);` The join table `ModelImageTag` will create one to many relationship with `ModelImage`, so its foreign key should be `ModelImageId`, not `ModelTagId`. Updated model creating code as follows:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<ModelImage> ModelImages { get; set; }
   public DbSet<ModelTag> ModelTags { get; set; }         

   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
   {
       optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=ModelImageDatabase.db");
   } 
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<ModelImageTag>()
           .HasKey(x => new { x.ModelImageId, x.ModelTagId });
       modelBuilder.Entity<ModelImageTag>()
           .HasOne(x => x.ModelImage)
           .WithMany(x => x.Tags)
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.ModelImageId);
       modelBuilder.Entity<ModelImageTag>()
           .HasOne(x => x.ModelTag)
           .WithMany(x => x.Images)
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.ModelTagId);
   }
}
```

Secondly, you don't have code snippet to add records to the database before you save changes to the database.

```
image.Tags.Add(iTag);
Context.ModelImages.Add(image);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Here is a complete sample code create many to many relationship between `ModelImage` and `ModelTag` by the join table `ModelImageTag` which may help you more clearly.

```
 var Context = new MyContext();
 ModelImage image = new ModelImage()
 {
     ModelImageId = 101,
     Tags = new List<ModelImageTag>()
 };
 ModelImage image2 = new ModelImage()
 {
     ModelImageId = 102,
     Tags = new List<ModelImageTag>()
 };
 ModelTag tag = new ModelTag()
 {
     ModelTagId = 201,
     Images = new List<ModelImageTag>()
 };
 ModelTag tag2 = new ModelTag()
 {
     ModelTagId = 202,
     Images = new List<ModelImageTag>()
 };
 ModelImageTag iTag = new ModelImageTag { ModelImage = image, ModelTag = tag };
 ModelImageTag iTag2 = new ModelImageTag { ModelImage = image, ModelTag = tag2 };
 ModelImageTag iTag3 = new ModelImageTag { ModelTag = tag, ModelImage = image2 };
 tag.Images.Add(iTag3);
 image.Tags.Add(iTag);
 image.Tags.Add(iTag2);
 Context.ModelImages.Add(image);
 Context.ModelImages.Add(image2);
 Context.ModelTags.Add(tag);
 Context.SaveChanges();
```

And the result:

[image]

More details please reference [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started). If you still have issues please provide a minimal reproduce project.

Comment: Hi Wu, finally getting time to check your suggestion... and bingo, there were two issues here. 1) foreign key, as just pointed out, but that was not the real issue. 2) I had not created ModelImage.Tags. Yep, 35 years of SW dev, and still did not properly instantiate a new class. LOL. So of course the .Tags.Add blew up.     On that note, can I instantiate collections inside a model entity upon creation (which is what I normally do with my classes, hence this error, as I deviated from my usual practice) or will EF throw up?

Comment: @J.H.  I upload the complete project [here](https://github.com/sunteenwu/CEntityFramework/tree/master/51EntityCoreMany) please test. If you still have issues, please provide your reproduce project and testing environment.

Comment: @J.H. I just saw you updated your comments. Sorry I'm a little confused about what you asked now.  Could you please detail it?  Can you run your project successfully now? What "does not contain  instantiating ModelImage.Tags." mean?

Comment: Hi, it means that when you instantiate a ModelImage you need to instantiate a Tags by image.Tags = new List<ModelImageTag>();. I usually design my classes so that any collections inside are instantiated upon create of a class instance. I am not sure whether that is advisable for classes in EF... So the question is: can I declare a constructor for ModelImage.Tags that is called when the instance of ModelImage is created. Or does EF not use the normal class constructor?

Comment: @J.H. In my opinion, EF has no relationship with how you constructor. So add the `image.tags` when the instance created or after created then add are both OK, but ensure it has the correct syntax and result. By the way, if my reply helped you could you please mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
ModelImage image = ....;
ModelTag tag = ...;

ModelImageTag iTag = new ModelImageTag { ModelImage = image, ModelTag = tag};
tag.Images.Add(iTag);
image.Tags.Add(iTag);

Context.SaveChanges();
```

Corrected code:

```
// in DbContext
DbSet<ModelImage> ModelImages;
DbSet<ModelTags> ModelTags;
DbSet<ModelImageTag> ModelImageTags;

// your code:

ModelImage image = ....;
ModelTag tag = ...;

ModelImageTag iTag = new ModelImageTag { ModelImage = image, ModelTag = tag};
tag.Images.Add(iTag);
image.Tags.Add(iTag);

// tell EF to add the above objects (without this, you got nothing)...
Context.ModelImages.Add(image);  // can also use AddRange()
Context.ModelTags.Add(tag);
Context.ModelImageTags.Add(iTag);

Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. I actually tossed the whole concept of Normform and made all tags a separated string in the asset entity. Way faster than anything EF...